# Is there any way that I can use Ubuntu 13.04 since it is no longer supported?

Tags: 13.04

I (regrettably) upgraded my desktop to Ubuntu 14.04 but have been disappointed in performance of certain applications.

Is it possible to download any software so that I can use 13.04 even though it is no longer supported?

Answer (score 3):

You *can* still use unsupported software, the only problem is that you wont recive official updates. But it's possible. One of the problems is that it's less secure than an up-to date version.

But I would install 12.04 in the meantime until 14.04 becomes more stable for you. Or run an unsupported distrobution like 13.04 or 13.10. It's mainly up to you if you want to take risk of running an unsupported version.

I currently run 13.10 on my laptop and it works fine.

Let's simplify this with an easy pro vs con.

**Pros**

- You can remain with the software and settings you are used to.
- No updates on your current system ensures that it wont break after an automatic upgrade (since there are none).

**Cons**

- Are you surfing on open networks a lot like, café, school, etc. Then it might be a good idea to have the latest security upgrades.
- Do you have a lot of new hardware then you might need the latest kernels which you only get on supported versions.
- No offical help, you can't get help on Ask Ubuntu because the problem might be gone on a supported release.

there might be more cons than pros, but I would continue on an usnupported release until the bugs are gone. You can easily test a supported release by installing it on like a USB or SD-card. Then you can try new kernels and see if your problem gets solved.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my problem. I simply needed to install another desktop environment. I installed cinnamon and now I can once again play steam games on Ultra. With wine, I can use a full-screen application without affecting resolution settings when closed. My original question to put it simply was that I couldn't use apt-get to install software because the archive.ubuntu repositories were taken down. I am glad that a resolution has been found and I thank everyone who contributed towards a solution.